# Gradle 6: get the list of implementation dependencies programmatically

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file for a java project that looks like this one:

```
group "com.example"

dependencies {
    implementation project(':project:project-base')
}
```

How do I get the list of implementation dependencies **programmatically**?

I would expect something like:

```
configurations.compile.dark.magick.moreMagicDependencies()
```

to return a set of dependencies to sift through, but I'm probably missing something important.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `resolvedConfiguration` like in the code below. Note that, "implementation" can't be resolved directly (try..).

But you can use eg. `compileClasspath` (if it fits your case); there are some other configurations that extend "implementation" (see the graph in [Java Library plugin..](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph)) .

Call the code below like `gradle :mymodule:dumpDependencies`

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.1.RELEASE'
}
task dumpDependencies {
  doLast {
    def resolved = configurations.compileClasspath.resolvedConfiguration
    println "files=$resolved.files"
    resolved.resolvedArtifacts.each {
      artifact-> println "artifact=$artifact"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**edit**
Note also that `compile` is deprecated, and if you use `implementation ..`, then the `compile` dependencies will be empty (you can check that with `gradle :module1:dependencies` of course).

Comment: Thank you Daniele, that's exactly what I need! Also thank you for the pointers and the suggestions: I'll use them to understand what's under the hood.

Comment: > Cannot change resolution strategy of dependency configuration 'test:compileClasspath' after it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Daniele's answer, this returns exactly what I'm looking for:

```
configurations.compileClasspath.incoming.dependencies.findAll {
    it.group && it.name && it.getProperties().get("dependencyProject")
}.collect {
    [group: it.group, name: it.name]
}
```